# Kill Angular 4 app process programmatically

Tags: node.js, angular, command-line-interface

We start the angular 4 app using `npm start` command which creates a process.
How do I stop this process using any kind of command or programmatically in general? 
I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23258421/how-to-stop-app-that-node-js-express-npm-start) and it seems useful. But I cannot figure out how or where do I set the title for the app?

Answer (score 1):

So I ended up setting `process.title` in my `webpack.common.js` file.

```
process.title = 'myApp'
```

And used the same title in my package.json file.

```
"scripts": {
    "stop": "pkill --signal SIGINT myApp"
}
```

This seemed to have kill the process.