# I can't stop npm

Tags: npm, discord.js

I can't stop/kill my discord.js bot (nodejs npm).

I tried kill:
[image]

And tried command:
npm stop

```
npm ERR! missing script: stop

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2019-07-09T09_14_24_836Z-debug.log
```

https://pastebin.com/v41PxTcN

Answer (score 1):

You didn't add the stop script.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23258421/how-to-stop-app-that-node-js-express-npm-start) will help you about that.

> You can make this really simple if you set in app.js: 
>   `process.title = myApp;`
>   And, then in scripts.json
>
> ```
> "scripts": {  
>    "start": "app.js"  
>    , "stop": "pkill --signal SIGINT myApp"  
> }
> ```

You said you tried kill. You didn't precise what signal you used. I'm pretty sure `kill -9 <PID>` will work (even if it's a *little bit* brutal and unnecessary).

You have a list of kill signals [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/317492/list-of-kill-signals).